# XSL - An attribute node (class) cannot be created after a child of the containing element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml to parse some html:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   version="2.0"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
   xmlns:d="data:,dpc"
   expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:import href="https://github.com/davidcarlisle/web-xslt/raw/main/htmlparse/htmlparse.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" html-version="5.0"/>

  <xsl:mode name="html"/>

  <xsl:template mode="html" match="b | strong | i | ul | ol | li | p | br | p | div | p/@style | div/@class" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template mode="html" match="script" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
       <head>
         <title>Test</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="orders">
    <h1>Orders</h1>
     <xsl:where-populated>
       <ol>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </ol>
     </xsl:where-populated>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="order">
     <li>Order
       <div>
         <h2>Comments</h2>
       <div>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="d:htmlparse(comments)" mode="html"/>
       </div>
      </div></li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I try to parse the following html:

```
<comments>
  <![CDATA[<div id="123" class="myclass">
    Some comment
  </div>]]>
</comments>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error executing XSLT at line 17 : An attribute node (class) cannot be created after a child of the containing element.
```

I take this is because I've defined the matching as `div/@class` and in the html I've got an id attribute before it.

How can I define the match so that the class attribute can appear in the html div element in any order regardless of what other attributes are defined?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k full example provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `xsl:apply-templates` processes the attribute `div/@id`, it chooses the default template, which produces a text node with the attribute value. At this point, the result tree looks so:

```xml
<div>123</div>
```

and when the attribute `div/@class` is processed next, it is too late for the attribute to be copied (as your first template wants to do).

The solution depends on what you want from the `div/@id` attribute or other attributes not covered by your first template. If you want to omit them, add a fallback template for other attributes:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="html" priority="-1"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
```

Comment: all other div attributes not covered by the first template should be omitted. Adding the fall back template with `div/@*` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I forgot the `xpath-default-namespace` in the fallback template, see my edited answer.

Comment: that seems to work but so does doing the following `<xsl:template mode="html" match="@*">` though not sure if that would be correct as I'm not an expert in xsl.

Comment: `match="@*"` is more general than `match="div/@*"`, if you want to omit attribute like `p/@id` as well, use the more general version.